# Add first letter to string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have `NSMutableArray` with data like this: "John Thomas" or "John M Lord". I need String with only "Thomas" or "Lord". If I have only word "Xavier", I need "X". I need check from the rear word to the space and get first letter "T" or "L".

My code:

```
for (int i=0; i< Data.count; i++)
{
    firstletter=[[Data objectAtIndex:i]substringToIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify on your usage of strings and / or arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know, whether NSMutableArray should be NSMutableString in your Q. However, isolating a single string:

```
NSString* fullName = …;
NSArray *parts = [fullName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSString *lastPart = [parts lastObject];
```